# Access history for NFS server

Tags: linux, nfs, auditd

I have a server (OS: Debian), in which nfs-kernel-server is installed and run. When a NFS client access or read, write to a file or directory in the NFS share directory, I want to capture and save all information about date, time, client-ip, action, directory... Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this would depend on how specific information you would need. We run alot of NFS servers, but on FreeBSD/Solaris. Over there we use Dtrace scripts to log each request. On Linux you could use Systemtap to achieve the same (Not sure what the performance impact will be). Brendan Gregg wrote a nice [article](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/15/using-systemtap/) about it